# Dojo ValidationTextBox not working with asp.net

Tags: dojo

My code is seperated by lots of controls on a masterpage, but on the master page I have this

```
<form dojoType="dijit.form.Form" id="form1" runat="server">
```

what gets injected into this is a validationtextbox, which is not validating

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true" 
                                                             placeholder="Your Name" 
                                                             missingMessage="Please enter your name."
                                                             intermediateChanges="true" 
                                                             name="Name" 
                                                             id="Name" 
                                                             type="text"
                                                             value="test"  />
```

anybody have any ideas why this dojo validate would not work? I get no red exclmation point at the end of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was somebody changed the themes css for the dijit widgets. The dojo was working correctly, I just couldn't see the actions because the css was not implemented properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the ASP injection process... if it's a dynamic insertion of the HTML above, you'll need to invoke dojo.parser.parse() on the fragment, otherwise Dojo will not render the widget and you'll just get a plain INPUT control